# Signed APK file upload fail

Tags: android

> You need to use a different package
>   Even after using refractor to change my projects name, I'm still getting this error every time I upload my signed APK

Comment: Every application your developer should have a unique application package name. Google will tell you that not allow you to upload until you change it to something unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says `package name`, not `project name`. Go to your `app/build.gradle` and change the `applicationId`.